# Convert text in a cell into a number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm creating a Google Form to make digital multiple choice tests. The answers that are given will be sent to Google Sheets. The answers are multiple choice so the data that I get consists of a limited number of possible answers.

In this spreadsheet I want to add points (like `3,3` or `5` or `10` or `0`) to the answers that are given depending on whether the answer is correct (or partially correct).

In the example spreadsheet every row consists of all the answers that are given by the student. This is automatically imported like this when a student sends in the form (in this testfile I have only one question). In B30:B33 I have put the four answers the multiple choice test has for this one question and in an adjacent column the number of points each answer is worth. I want to connect the points to the answer that is given in D2 (which is a wrong answer and should result in `0`).

How can I do this?

Comment: May I can help you, do you have the spreadsheet in english or provide more details on the questions and answers?! Did you checked if there is a spreadsheet api to get and update the spreadsheets?

Comment: Language shouldn't be important in this matter. All I need is a script that says: if the answer in D2 = blabla give 10 points, if the answer is blablabla then give 0 points. It would be nice if the result in D2 can be compared with B30:B33 and then put the points that correspond with each answer (B30-->A30, B31--> A31, B32 --> A32, B33 --> A33) in another cell so I can later sum up and divide all the points.

Comment: You need to start somewhere, then the people will help you out.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try! Thanks in advance for the interest in helping me out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With enough responses your range of result scores is likely to get in the way where it is so I suggest moving it to another sheet and giving it a name, such as NamedRange1. But I would swap over the columns first (answers to the left of their scores) - and replacing the `0`s to suit with `3,3` `5` and `10`.

Then in your form responses sheet `Formulierreacties 1`:

```
=vlookup(D2;NamedRange1;2;0)
```

Comment: I understand that I have to create another sheet, but I don't understand the code completely. It now returns the text in B32, but not the value in that corresponds with that answer (in C32: 10). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I was experimenting with something else, so the formula was not there at that time. But now it works. I forgot to add the column where the numbers were. Thank you for your help.